# What is the good way to input \ in auctex and _ when cdlatex is on?

Tags: emacs, auctex

I would like to input \ in auctex but when I type \, a minibuffer will prompt out to ask me to choose a macro. I think it is a good feature but sometimes the only thing I need is a real \ . Is there a solution?

And, I would like to type _ in my text but when cdlatex is on, it will add $$ around it and see it as a subscript.

Looking for answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `quoted-insert` function. It's bound by default to <kbd>C-q</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you set [`TeX-electric-escape`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex.html#index-TeX_002delectric_002descape) to non-nil in your init file.  If you want to restore the normal behavior of `\` you should remove this setting, otherwise you can insert a character literally using <kbd>C-q</kbd> when you want to insert just a `\`.